# How would I change the value of a UILabel from a different class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I am a student trying to make an app in Xcode, and I have run into an issue to which I cannot figure out the solution. I want to access a string I have stored in another class and make it the label text of my ViewController.

In my ViewController, I call a different class, which then calls through an API and finds me a string detailing the weather in a certain place. This is what my call looks like from my ViewController class

```
func getWeather() {
   
    manager = DataManager()
    manager.fetchData(query: getQueryString();
}
```

And this is what the call looks like from the DataManager Class

```
  func rainyWeatherPopulate(str: String){

    LoadEvents.loadEvents(type: EventType.rain, str: str)
    
}
```

in the loadEvents function, I get a string detailing the type of weather that I want to put as text of a UILabel in my ViewController class, and I am not sure how to do so

Is there any way that I can pass an instance of my ViewController to my loadEvents static function or any other way in which I can set the text of a UILabel in my ViewController from the LoadEvents class?

Comment: As a general rule, you should treat a view controller's views as private. (This is an example of the principle of "encapsulation", where you keep the internal details of each part of your program (class) hidden from each other, and only use well defined public interfaces between classes) @jnpdx solution of passing in a closure solves the problem elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many potential ways to solve this problem, but one is by passing a closure to be used upon completion of the call.

So, it might look like this in your use case:

```
class DataManager {
    func fetchData(query: String, onComplete: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        LoadEvents.loadEvents(type: .rain, str: query, onComplete: onComplete)
    }
}

enum EventType {
    case rain
}

class LoadEvents {
    static func loadEvents(type: EventType, str: String, onComplete: (String) -> Void) {
        //load the data
        //then, when it's done, call the completion
        onComplete("returnedData")
    }
}

func getWeather() {
    let manager = DataManager()
    let uiLabel = UILabel()
    manager.fetchData(query: "queryString", onComplete: { result in
        uiLabel.text = result
    })
}
```

I had to mock out some stuff (like `EventType`) and I had no information about the types of events you're loading, so I just used a generic `String` for the return type, but the concept is here.

**How it works**:

1. In getWeather, there's a closure called `onComplete` that will get data back once everything has completed. `result` holds (obviously) the result -- in this case a string, and it sets `uiLabel`'s `text` property to that value.
2. `LoadEvents` does whatever it needs to and then upon finishing, calls `onComplete` and sends the results back through the closure.

Comment: Passing in a closure is a good, clean solution to the problem. (Voted)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say jnpdx's solution of passing a closure to your data manager is the best answer.

Another way you could do this is to add a delegate property to your data manager. The only thing you know about the delegate is that it conforms to a specific protocol. You'd then invoke methods on the delegate from the data manager that would tell the delegate about data that was available for display. The delegate would decide what to do with that data.

I mention this as an alternative method, but would suggest using closures as jnpdx recommends in their answer.